# MySQL: Select last row in each aggregate group

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I want to select the last row of each `GROUP BY` aggregate in MySQL.

For example, if I write `GROUP BY foo`, and two rows have a `foo = 'bar'`, I want to select the last row (as ordered by `id`) of those two (I want to select the `message` column of the last row in each aggregate clause, as ordered by `id` and `GROUP`ed by `foo`).

How can I do this?

Table definition, as requested:

```
+-----------------+
| id  foo message |
+-----------------+
| 1   bar hey     |
| 2   joe hi      |
| 3   bar hello   |
+-----------------+
```

I want to get something like the following:

```
+-------------+
| foo message |
+-------------+
| bar hello   |
| joe hi      |
+-------------+
```

It gives me `hello`, because `hello` is the last row with `foo = 'bar'`, as ordered by `id`.

Comment: please add your table definition it will help others

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka Thanks for the reminder, please refer to the edit.

Comment: How do you define **last row**? Based on highest value of **id**?

Comment: @1000111 Yes, it would be the last row as ordered by `id`, so yes, highest `id` value.

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly. Some answers are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 
footable.foo,
footable.message
FROM footable
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    foo,
    MAX(id) max_id
    FROM footable
    GROUP BY foo
) AS t
ON footable.foo = t.foo AND footable.id = t.max_id
ORDER BY footable.id DESC;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5435b/1/0)

Running the query on your given input you will get an output like below:

```
| foo | message |
|-----|---------|
| bar |   hello |
| joe |      hi |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` and subquery:

```
select *
from yourtable
where (id, foo) in (
    select max(id), foo from yourtable group by foo
)
```

### SQLFiddle Demo